# Titanium Alloy Models

Tags: models, titanium-alloy, password-encryption, sjcl

I am working with Titanium Alloy Models and want to encrypt the password before storing into the model and decrypt while getting it. I want model to return such data.

Comment: i have made a function models and then referring to that function `'extendModel : function(Model) {
_.extend(Model.prototype, {
encrypt : function(key, value) {
var encrypted = sjcl.encrypt("password", value);
this.set(key, encrypted);
},`
But the thing is that i want to override the default set and get methods without ruining my entire code.